# Updating the Grid.ColumnSpan doesnt change the column span of the rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf, grid-layout, xamdatagrid

```
<Window x:Class="ColumnSpan_Check.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
            <Rectangle.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2"/>
                </Style>
            </Rectangle.Style>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Why cant i get the rectangle to occupy two columns here ? I wanted the rectangle to occupy two columns when a certain condition is met (using a datatrigger ) the issue turns out that the datatrigger gets fired but the layout of rectangle doesn't update to occupy two columns.

Comment: Post the full XAML, and DataContext code.

Comment: There you go i copied the entire XAML here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is right there in the XAML:

You're setting the `Grid.ColumnSpan` attached property in two places, directly in the `Rectangle` tag and again in the style.  The first setting takes precedence over the second.

Since you want the Rectangle to occupy two columns when a condition is met, just remove the `Grid.ColumnSpan` from the `Rectangle` tag and put it into the Style & you're good to go.  Like this:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Column="0">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="1"/>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2"/>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
 /Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 1):

It could just be a typing error, but this property wouldn't work:

```
public Visibility GridColVisibility
{
    get { return GridColVisibility; }
    set { GridColVisibility= value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => GridColVisibility); }
}
```

You can't use the property name *inside* the property like that... you'd get an error. You need a `private` member to back your property... something like this:

```
private Visibility gridColVisibility;
public Visibility GridColVisibility
{
    get { return gridColVisibility; }
    set { gridColVisibility = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => GridColVisibility); }
}
```

However... I'm going to assume that this was just a typing error.

Looking at your `DataTrigger`, I can't really see anything that is obviously wrong, so I can only assume that your `Binding Path` is incorrect... if it is, then look in the Output Window in Visual Studio and you should find details of the error. This small example shows that it *is* definitely possible to set the `Grid.ColumnSpan` property in a `DataTrigger`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Fill="LightGreen">
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

So I think that unfortunately, given the information that you have provided, *you* are the only one that can really find your mistake... I'd take a good look at that `Binding Path` if I were you.

Comment: thanks for the reply Sheridian , appreciate it , the property was a typo i was just playing around with the Grid.ColumnSpan property i cant get your sample code to work at all . In fact i can get it to work if i just set the Grid.Columnspan to 2 in a style a

Comment: Thanks, i was able to resolve the issue from the above comment , will close this question .

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by removing the Grid.ColumnSpan property from the button .
Thanks everyone for your help.